# Magento 2: Is there a way to send money over to a customer?

Tags: magento2, payment, paypal

I'm currently looking around for a way to send money over to a customer, thus far the only way I've found is through refunds, but that doesn't seem like the most optimal way to do it. Is there a built in way to make such payments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other built in way to send money to customers.
You need customer card/account details/PayPal account before you can pay to them.
I guess the easiest option would be through PayPal by asking customers PayPal account.

So, whatever you do you need to some development for that.